# How to fit a list view to the bottom in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am new to Android, and I am facing many issues for layout. I have a screen with `Toolbar` on the top.  Below that, I have an `ImageView`, and below the `ImageView`, a `ListView`. I am facing a problem with laying out the `ListView` height. Since my `ListView` is the last item on the screen, I would like it to fit with the remaining area of the screen. This, is I would like to resize the `ListView` dynamically so that it fits.  Below is the layout that I set for the screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.team.sidhesh.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="617dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorAccent"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sliderTempImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/slider_image_height"
            android:src="@drawable/slider_image1"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/slider_seperator_height"
            android:src="@drawable/slider_seperator"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_view"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        </ListView>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of your view's parent ViewGroup.

For RelativeLayout parents, Jeetendra Choudhary's answer of `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` will work fine.

For LinearLayout parents, you should have your view be the last child of the layout and set `android:layout_weight="1"` to have it fill the space to the bottom.

For FrameLayout parents, you should set `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` on your view.

You should not use an `AppBarLayout` as your root `ViewGroup`. I would recommend something like this, with a `LinearLayout` or `FrameLayout` as the root `ViewGroup`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorAccent"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sliderTempImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/slider_image_height"
            android:src="@drawable/slider_image1"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/slider_seperator_height"
            android:src="@drawable/slider_seperator"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Additionally, `ListView` is fairly dated. I would recommend looking into using `RecyclerView` from the support library instead.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html

Answer (score 0):

You can simply enclose your `ListView` inside a `LinearLayout` with height `match_parent` and setting `gravity` to `bottom`. Something like this,

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```